# Using Python to distinguish between lines with one dot and lines with two dots

Tags: python, parsing, separator

I have a large file which I want to format in a certain manner. File input example:

```
DVL1    03220   NP_004412.2 VANGL2  02758   Q9ULK5  in vitro    12490194
PAX3    09421   NP_852124.1 MEOX2   02760   NP_005915.2 in vitro;yeast 2-hybrid 11423130
VANGL2  02758   Q9ULK5  MAGI3   11290   NP_001136254.1  in vitro;in vivo    15195140
```

And this is how I want it to become:

```
DVL1    03220   NP_004412   VANGL2  02758   Q9ULK5
PAX3    09421   NP_852124   MEOX2   02760   NP_005915
VANGL2  02758   Q9ULK5  MAGI3   11290   NP_001136254
```

To summarize:

- if the line has 1 dot, that dot is deleted along with the number after it and a \t is added, so the output line will only have 6 tab-separated values
- if the line has 2 dots, those dots are deleted along with the numbers after them and a \t is added, so the output line will only have 6 tab-separated values
- if the line has no dots, maintain the first 6 tab-separated values

My idea is currently something like this:

```
for line in infile:
    if "." in line: # thought about this and a line.count('.') might be better, just wasn't capable to make it work
        transformed_line = line.replace('.', '\t', 2) # only replaces the dot; want to replace dot plus next first character
        columns = transformed_line.split('\t')
        outfile.write('\t'.join(columns[:8]) + '\n') # if i had a way to know the position of the dot(s), i could join only the desired columns
    else:
        columns = line.split('\t')
        outfile.write('\t'.join(columns[:5]) + '\n') # this is fine
```

Hope I explained myself ok.
Thanks for you guys effort.

Comment: this can easily be done with `sed`. I guess you want `python` because it's part of a bigger program (?)

Comment: Yup, this is just part of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
    with open('data1.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line=line.split()[:6]
            line=map(lambda x:x[:x.index('.')] if '.' in x else x,line)  #if an element has '.' then
                                                                         #remove that dot else keep the element as it is
            print('\t'.join(line))
```

**output:**

```
DVL1    03220   NP_004412   VANGL2  02758   Q9ULK5
PAX3    09421   NP_852124   MEOX2   02760   NP_005915
VANGL2  02758   Q9ULK5  MAGI3   11290   NP_001136254
```

**Edit:**

as @mgilson suggested the line `line=map(lambda x:x[:x.index('.')] if '.' in x else x,line)` can be replaced by simply `line=map(lambda x:x.split('.')[0],line)`

Comment: Can you explain step by step what you did? I'm not that good at programming.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But I'm guessing, why after 'in'?

Comment: I edited my solution, I removed those `in` related lines. Just use `line.split()[0:6]` to fetch the  first 6 columns.

Comment: It is amazing man, just had to add a + '\n' after print('\t'.join(line), cause the output was just one big line.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your lambda, why not just use `x.split('.')[0]`?

Comment: @mgilson thanks! that just didn't came to my mind. I'll edit my solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    newlines=(re.sub(r'\.\d+','',old_line) for old_line in f)
    newlines=['\t'.join(line.split()[:6]) for line in newlines]
```

Now you have a list of lines with the '.number' portions removed.  As far as I can tell, your problem isn't well enough constrained to make this whole thing work in 1 pass with regex, but it'll work with 2.

Comment: its a regex... that replaces a "." followed by 1 or more #'s with nothing

Comment: It doesn't quite give the desired output (yet).  Still working on it... (I didn't realize that everything after the second dot should be truncated).

Comment: I got the idea, but I can't seem to find the correct spot to add the line to.
Should I just do:

"import re

for line in infile:
    new_line=re.sub(r'\.\d+','',old_line)"

?

Comment: Wow, that's pretty well thought. Thanks, would never realize it by myself!

Answer (score 1):

I figured somebody should do this with a single regex, so...

```
import re
beast_regex = re.compile(r'(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+?)(?:\.\d+)?\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+?)(?:\.\d+)?\s+in.*')
with open('data.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        match = beast_regex.match(line)
        print('\t'.join(match.groups())
```

Comment: (+1) -- although, this is pretty sensitive to the position of the '`.`'.  e.g. (if I'm reading it correctly), you couldn't have 'foo.1' in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a simple regex:

```
import re
for line in infile:
    line=re.sub(r'\.\d+','\t',line)
columns = line.split('\t')
outfile.write('\t'.join(columns[:5]) + '\n')
```

this replaces any "." followed by one or more digits with a tab character.